The de Rham homomorphism is a ring homomorphism
I'd like to show that the de Rham isomorphism $I \colon H^k_{dR}(M) \rightarrow H^k(M,\mathbb{R})$ is a ring homomorphism. That is, I'd like to show that the following chain of equalities holds up to cohomology equivalence:
\begin{equation*}
I(\omega \wedge \eta)(\sigma) = \int_\sigma\omega \wedge \eta = \int_{\Delta^{p+q}}\sigma^*\omega \wedge \sigma^*\eta \overset{(*)}{=} \int_{\Delta^p}(\sigma \circ f_p)^*\omega \cdot \int_{\Delta^q}(\sigma \circ b_q)^*\eta = (I(\omega) \cup I(\eta))(\sigma)
\end{equation*}
for each $(p+q)$-simplex, where $f_p \colon \Delta^p \rightarrow \Delta^{p+q}$ sends $e_i$ to $e_i$ and $b_q \colon \Delta^q \rightarrow \Delta^{p+q}$ sends $e_i$ to $e_{p+i}$. Clearly, I'm missing the equality marked with $(*)$.

not an answer, but you need to show something weaker, namely for cohomology classes and not for cochains (i.e. the equation should be true only up to exact terms)

yes, of course. I wrote this in a rush. I'll fix my question immediately, thank you very much <3.
